# SQL Server DateTime format from automatic export script

Tags: sql-server, datetime

When using the mssql script generation with data the datetime is exported with a cast:

```
CAST(0x00009E0E0095524F AS DateTime)
```

Does anyone know what format is used ?

The date in the example is shown as `2010-10-13 09:03:39.783`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upper 4 bytes = days from 01 Jan 1900, lower 4 = time of day

It's the internal storage of datetime which is 8 bytes as two 4 byte integers, one with whole days, the other as fraction of day.

```
DECLARE @inttop bigint,  @TheValue bigint
SET @inttop = POWER(CAST(2 AS bigint), 32)
SET @TheValue = CAST(0x00009E0E0095524F AS bigint) 

SELECT
    --days since 01 Jan 1900
    @TheValue / @inttop,
    --fractional time of day
    CAST(@TheValue % @inttop AS float) / @inttop

--and confirm it
SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, @TheValue / @inttop, 0),
    CAST(CAST((@TheValue % @inttop) AS float) / @inttop AS datetime)
```

Comment: I am trying to take the dump output from sql server to load into postgresql.  It is providing a datetime as this cast.  I ultimately want to use sed to convert the test to right format, but if I to this

Comment: Strike the above it took me too long to edit it.  I am using this technique to use sed to alter a script from sqlserver to postgresql with to_timestamp(((x'00009E0E0095524F'::bigint)/(2^32))::real * 86400) - 70 * Interval '1 year' gives me 2010-10-12 01:05:37.5+01.  I seem to be slightly out - not sure why yet

Comment: solved - to_timestamp((((x'00009E0E0095524F'::bigint)/(2^32))::real * 86400) + extract('epoch'from timestamp '1900-01-01'))